# Is it possible to upgrade to the latest version of Okular?

Tags: release-freya, updates

I'm running elementary OS 0.3.2. I use Okular as my main PDF reader since I believe it is miles above Evince regarding features, ease of use, speed, etc.

Currently, I have version 0.19.3 installed, which I obtained simply by:

```
sudo apt-get install okular
```

and the [current version is 0.24](https://okular.kde.org/).

Can Okular be upgraded to its latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build it from it's source: https://okular.kde.org/download.php

However that would require to get a complete KDE4 Development Set.

Comment: Why the hell should that not be correct?